# Create multiple grids from one data source without duplicating that source

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, kendo-grid

Say I have the following in my Razor:

```
@model FooClass

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BarClass>(Model.Bar)
   // Grid code and properties to select fields A, B, C
)

@(Html.Kendo().Grid<BarClass>(Model.Bar)
   // Grid code and properties to select fields D, E, F
)
```

The entire `Bar` property from the model is rendered into the HTML twice - once for each grid. Now, I could select a new anonymous object in each grid and base the columns on that. But - That won't render the column headers to use my `Display` attribute.

In this page, I have a class with MANY properties and these properties will drive around a dozen separate grids. So it would be quite nice to not have my entire object serialized for each grid over and over.

Is there any way to do this? My reasoning is that I can cut down the size of the page and help performance by eliminating the repetition of this model.

Comment: Actually you can't pass an anonymous object to the Kendo grid. So I've created helper classes with only the metrics I need per grid. This isn't a great solution because I need to title everything rather than let it use the display attribute, but it's working. Took my page from 2.3 mb to 150 kb.

Answer (score 0):

I hate to answer my own question this quick. After further research it seems this is not possible. The solution is to create many small models and populate them one by one, then manually select and fill them. This avoids serializing the large model over and over when sending the page to the client.